Making sure the user selects a feature of a vector layer and not the raster below
I'm working on PyQGIS console and I have a problem: when I click on a feature of my vector layer, raises the Python error:
"AttributeError: 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'selectedFeatures"
And I think I know the reason: I'm using, as last layer (so below) OpenStreetMap, a raster layer. Indeed, if I disactive this, the error doesn't raise. But for me is important that OpenStreetMap is always visible, so has someone any solution to make sure the program understands that user clicked on a vector layer's feature and not on the raster?
Here is the code that I used to ask the user to select one or more features:
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
        
        for layer in canvas.layers():
            
             selected = layer.selectedFeatures()
        
        w = self

        #this is the function running from an other connected script

        itrd.timeOutEhrtsBuild(selected, w, self)


Could you share the related code lines?

I can guess that perhaps you just copied the code from this answer without adapting it to suit your need. I.e. you are iterating over all checked layers. If you need to do that, you should check the type of each layer e.g. if isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer):. Otherwise, I would suggest letting the user select the layer with a QgsMapLayerComboBox filtered to only show vector layers.
